# Parellelly is wrong usage

Tags: word-usage

What are the other ways to say it other than "in parallel".
example: "Do this bit of work now. And in parallel  do some research on the new prospect"

Comment: "Concurrently".

Comment: "Simultaneously"; "At the same time"; "While you're doing that"

Comment: "[in the] meanwhile/meantime".

Answer (score 1):

"Simultaneously" is the best word. According to [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/simultaneously), it means:

> At the same time.